# Font size of Codeigniter 4 watermark not changing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to increase the font size of Codeiginter watermark but it's not changing no matter what number I put.. On codeigniter Documentation it says:
"fontSize The font size to use. When using the GD handler with the system font, valid values are between 1-5"
But even if I put 5 or 1 or even 100, size still remain the same.
Am I missing something?

This is the code

```
$image = \Config\Services::image()
->withFile($img)
->text('Bsth copyright', [
   'color'      => '#5fcf98',
   'opacity'    => 0.1,
   'withShadow' => false,
   'hAlign'     => 'center',
   'vAlign'     => 'center',
   'fontSize'   => 90
])
->save('upload/' . $files[$i]);
```

The watermark is small as shown in image, i'm trying to make the copyright text take the full width of the image [the small copyright img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2QVX.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to use a different font? There is a fontPath option but check the doco on its use.

Comment: vAlign uses top, middle, bottom. You are using center which isn't a valid value.